# Issues while accessing global variable from a python module in a different dir and file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having issues while using the global variable import from a different module. I did go through sample answer provided earlier but not able fix the issues. Need some direction.

**I want to use the variables which are declared in an another module in utils.commonmodules.py.
Below code base of commonmodules.py and dq_exec.py.
dq_exec.py imports commonmodules.py and try to use variable (app_dq_db whicch is global)**

```
1.commonmodules.py

from utils.cfg import config
from utils.sparkSession import *
from utils.logsession import getloggingSession
import pandas as pd
import subprocess
############### Modules Imported #####################
logger=getloggingSession()
def getDqDefaultConfigParam():
    logger.info('Getting all the parameters from Config')
    global prc_cntrl_db
    global app_dq_db
    global dq_grp_config_tbl
    prc_cntrl_db = config.get('hive_db_details', 'prc_cntrl_db')
    logger.info(script_nm + ' -> prc_cntrl_db :: '+ prc_cntrl_db)
    app_dq_db = config.get('hive_dq_config_tbl', 'app_dq_db')
    logger.info(script_nm + ' -> app_dq_db :: '+ app_dq_db)
```

Imported the above module along with other

```
2. dq_exec.py 
    from utils.commonmodules import getDqDefaultConfigParam
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        getDqDefaultConfigParam()
        print("prc_name",getDqDefaultConfigParam.app_dq_db)
```

spark-submit /data/1/appgcb/bin/dq/spark/gen_dq_check_exec.py ${app_id} ${prc_name} ${prc_run_id} ${prc_start_dt} ${prc_run_dt} ${params_detl}

```
Output: I am able to see the values after calling the getDqDefaultConfigParam()but not able to access.
20191220084328 INFO: Line - 80 Getting all the parameters from Config
20191220084328 INFO: Line - 87 /data/1/appgcb/bin/dq/spark/gen_dq_check_exec.py -> prc_cntrl_db :: app_gcb_stg
20191220084328 INFO: Line - 89 /data/1/appgcb/bin/dq/spark/gen_dq_check_exec.py -> app_dq_db :: app_gcb_stg
20191220084328 INFO: Line - 91 /data/1/appgcb/bin/dq/spark/gen_dq_check_exec.py -> dq_grp_config_tbl :: dq_group_config
20191220084328 INFO: Line - 93 /data/1/appgcb/bin/dq/spark/gen_dq_check_exec.py -> dq_rule_config_tbl :: dq_rule_config
20191220084328 INFO: Line - 95 /data/1/appgcb/bin/dq/spark/gen_dq_check_exec.py -> dq_grp_config_colList :: ['dq_grp_name','app_id','prc_name','schema_name','table_nm','table_filter']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  **File "/data/1/appgcb/bin/dq/spark/gen_dq_check_exec.py", line 110, in <module>
    print("prc_name",getDqDefaultConfigParam.app_dq_db)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'app_dq_db'**
```

Comment: Variables created/used in functions don't become attributes of that function...

Comment: You aren't trying to access a local variable, rather, you are trying to access a *local* variable, which is not possible outside of it's scope (that is why it is a local variable). It *seems* you believe that local variables become attributes of the function that uses them, but that is not the case.

Comment: Also declaring a variable as `global` doesn't immediately make it available outside the function if you haven't yet decalred it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`global x` means make `x` available in all scopes, not assign it to be an attribute of my function. If you want to assign attributes, realistically you need a class.

**Using global variables:**

`my_module.py:`

```
x = 12
def y():
    global x
    x = 13
```

`main.py:`

```
import my_module

print(my_module.x)
my_module.y()
print(my_module.x)
```

`output:`

```
12
13
```

**Or if you really need it as an attribute:**

`my_module.py:`

```
class z:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 13
```

`main.py:`

```
import my_module

my_z = my_module.z()
print(my_z.x)
```

`output:`

```
12
```

**EDIT:**

So, for your case, replace

```
def getDqDefaultConfigParam():
    logger.info('Getting all the parameters from Config')
    global prc_cntrl_db
    global app_dq_db
    global dq_grp_config_tbl
    prc_cntrl_db = config.get('hive_db_details', 'prc_cntrl_db')
    logger.info(script_nm + ' -> prc_cntrl_db :: '+ prc_cntrl_db)
    app_dq_db = config.get('hive_dq_config_tbl', 'app_dq_db')
    logger.info(script_nm + ' -> app_dq_db :: '+ app_dq_db)
```

with

```
class getDqDefaultConfigParam_cls:
    def __init__(self):
        logger.info('Getting all the parameters from Config')
        self.prc_cntrl_db = config.get('hive_db_details', 'prc_cntrl_db')
        logger.info(script_nm + ' -> prc_cntrl_db :: '+ prc_cntrl_db)
        self.app_dq_db = config.get('hive_dq_config_tbl', 'app_dq_db')
        logger.info(script_nm + ' -> app_dq_db :: '+ app_dq_db)

getDqDefaultConfigParam = getDqDefaultConfigParam_cls()
```

in `commonmodules.py`.

You can now use `getDqDefaultConfigParam.app_dq_db`, as `getDqDefaultConfigParam` is an instance of a class which has the correct attributes.

Comment: If you're doing it like this, why do the variables need to be `global` still?

Comment: That's correct. I just updated to class and use the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you returned the variables you needed in the `getDqDefaultConfigParam` function.

You could make this change in `commonmodules.py`:

```
def getDqDefaultConfigParam():
    logger.info('Getting all the parameters from Config')
    prc_cntrl_db = config.get('hive_db_details', 'prc_cntrl_db')
    logger.info(script_nm + ' -> prc_cntrl_db :: '+ prc_cntrl_db)
    app_dq_db = config.get('hive_dq_config_tbl', 'app_dq_db')
    logger.info(script_nm + ' -> app_dq_db :: '+ app_dq_db)
    return prc_cntrl_db, app_dq_db, dq_grp_config_tbl
```

And then unpack them in `dq_exec.py`:

```
prc_cntrl_db, app_dq_db, dq_grp_config_tbl = getDqDefaultConfigParam()
print(f'prc_name {app_dq_db}')
```

---

As a side note, functions I find these variable and function names very hard to understand -- they are all so similar. Is there no way to name them better?